# VS2010: Where do i find the local settings

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have renamed my existing user folder in C:\Documents and Settings to reset my windows desktop and that created a new user folder for me.

This also reset everything including my setting of IE, Visual Studio etc.

Now I want to revert my VS2010 setting to that of earlier. How is this possible?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075.aspx

Answer (score 0):

well, hopefully you still have your old My Docs folder. VS usually creates Visual Studio 2010 (depending on the version) on your My Documents folder. Copy over that folder and you should be good to go :)